# Android Complex View: manually create or using layout xml file?

Tags: android, view

I need to create an activity(view) that shows several lists, for example:

(text)Fruits:
(item)apple
(item)orange
(item)pear

(text)Veges:
(item)Cabbage
(item)Carrot

all data are read from a database, so I cannot determine them and create layout file(xml) for them, what's is the best way to create this? Also, list items are clickable which directs users to another screen.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, the each (text) and (item) occupies one line, so they look like a list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView`s are filled with data using `Adapter`s. So, you can use a single layout with a `ListView` and change adapters depending on what you want to display.

Have a look at [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) interface.

And if you want to have several `ListView`s, then in your case I'd use a single `ExpandableListView` widget with differet groups like Fruits, Veges and so on.

Comment: Will ExpandableListView work if I do not know how many groups are there, until read data from database?

Comment: Yes, it will. Groups and items are retrieved from a class that implements the `ExpandableListAdapter` interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a database using sqlite already, U can use cursor adapter to fetch the data from your database. Its really simple. try to find out how to fetch data from database and how to insert values into listview using cursor adapter.